# Arch Linux, "hang" on "Reached target Graphical Interface"

Tags: arch-linux, desktop, display-manager

**EDIT:** I just tried `gnome` and `gdm` and it worked flawlessly. So something with the virtualbox packages and the SDDM package seems to not work.

At first this question looks like this one ([Arch Linux stuck at boot (reached target Graphical Interface)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330999/arch-linux-stuck-at-boot-reached-target-graphical-interface)), however, I can still change to a different TTY.

Anyways, the following used to work before, but results in a `core dump` of `sddm` since recently. Interestingly enough, systems I simply update, which used this install method, do still work, but new installations lead to the issues below.

When installing Arch Linux in VirtualBox with Windows 10 as host system, I use this minimum [non]working example that is based on the official Arch Installer guide and used to work:

```
parted

mklabel GPT
mkpart ESP fat32 1MiB 513MiB
mkpart primary ext4 513MiB 100%
set 1 boot on
quit

mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1

mount /dev/sda2 /mnt

mkdir -p /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

pacstrap /mnt base base-devel \
              virtualbox-guest-modules-arch \
              virtualbox-guest-utils \
              sddm plasma

arch-chroot /mnt bootctl --path=/boot install

cat <<-END > /mnt/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
title Arch Linux
linux /vmlinuz-linux
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
options root=PARTUUID=$( blkid -s PARTUUID -o value /dev/sda2 ) rw
END

cat <<-END > /mnt/boot/loader/loader.conf
default arch
timeout 4
editor  0
END

genfstab -pU /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab

arch-chroot /mnt systemctl enable sddm

arch-chroot /mnt useradd -m -G wheel -s /bin/bash bob
```

It hangs on "reached target Graphical interface" but I can still use `ctrl+alt+F2` in contrast to this question ([Arch Linux stuck at boot (reached target Graphical Interface)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330999/arch-linux-stuck-at-boot-reached-target-graphical-interface)) and calling `journalctl -b -p err` yields:

[image]
[image]

And here with more info:
[image]
[image]

Comment: unfortunately my VBox currently produces the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that SDDM/KDE no longer pulls xorg-server packages automatically. So if one adds the `xorg-server` package it works.

Found solution here: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/605#issuecomment-275938076

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (or a very similar issue). It would stop at reached target graphical interface and I could switch tty. Fom there I could restart gdm and after a couple of tries it would start.

If you are using the proprietary nvidia graphics drivers with xorg you can use this solution. To fix this, open `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` and uncomment `#WaylandEnable=false`.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with similar symptoms after migrating some disks to new hardware, but could see nothing fishy in the logs after enabling debug logging.  The machine also had no dm software installed.  I also noticed that some services weren't starting.

It turns out some of the target files under /etc (eg `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` were not symlinks as they are meant to be, and may have just had stale code in them.  I fixed my issue by removing all non-symlink target files and recreating them with `systemctl enable` or just manually linking to the appropriate target under `/usr/lib/systemd/` - The specific target that was causing my failure was a stale `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service`