# Latest system update on Arch + Gnome hangs at "session 1 of user"

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

Just ran the latest updates on my Arch + Gnome system and on reboot it hangs with the last message of "Session 1 of user elijah". I can press `ctrl + alt + f3` to get a TTY, but not F2 TTY, and then I get into a terminal which I can login with and then run `systemctl restart gdm.service` and then I get Gnome up and running. However, on reboot the same issue persists.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611869/boot-hangs-at-reached-target-graphical-interface-on-arch-after-system-update?noredirect=1&lq=1. The solution is slightly different and the problem is different too.

Comment: [you answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657730/72456) that solution is same, so why you still complained it's not duplicated?  even question is also same

Comment: It is actually a slightly different answer, the way to enter the TTY is different in this scenario. It hangs at a different scenario, so it really is a different question. There is definitely overlap, but it is different.

Comment: those definitely needs run in tty, so with or without it, actuall answers were remain the same and you may want to add that in your previous answer too.

Comment: Well, I disagree. And my answer here doesn't actually fully work, and I am still looking for the right answer. So by closing this issue as a duplicate, I am less likely to get the right answer.

Comment: OK, [look at your own answer again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657730/72456) specially step7. if it doesn't answer/resolve your question you better off delete it and probably add it as an [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 0):

K, so I found my other question/answer [Boot hangs at "Reached target Graphical Interface" on Arch after system update (no virtualbox)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611869/boot-hangs-at-reached-target-graphical-interface-on-arch-after-system-update) and the answer is the same.

1. `ctrl + alt + f3` to enter a TTY
2. `systemctl disable gdm.service`
3. `yay --remove gdm`
4. `yay --sync --refresh gdm`
5. `systemctl enable gdm.service`
6. `reboot`
7. Works!

Comment: This actually only sorta works, it seems that after about 2 reboots the issue comes back. So it works a little, and gets the system usable again, but I'm still looking for a longer term fix.